# JavaFX word-wrap on a Treeview, TreeItem/TreeCell

Tags: java, css, javafx, treeview, word-wrap

I want to have a collapsible list so I'm using a TreeView, but longer strings are giving horizontal scrollbars instead of word wrapping.  I've tried using the CSS property `-fx-wrap-text` on the `.tree-cell` class but unfortunately nothing seems to happen.

Are `TreeCell`s not meant to span more than one line?  What alternative is there if that's the case?

Here's an image of what it looks like now:

[image]

*test.css*

```
.tree-cell {
        -fx-wrap-text: true;
        -fx-text-fill: blue;
    }
```

*subjects.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication1.FXMLDocumentController">
    <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="182.0" layoutY="14.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Click Me!" />
    <TextField fx:id="filterSubject" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="14.0" />
    <TreeView fx:id="subjectList" editable="true" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="61.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="365.0" />
    <stylesheets>
            <URL value="@test.css" />
    </stylesheets>  
</AnchorPane>
```

*subjects.txt* - just pairs of text where the first is subject, and second is description.

```
1
Somewhat long string that I want to wordwrap.
2
Somewhat long string that I want to wordwrap.
3
Somewhat long string that I want to wordwrap.
```

*FXMLDocumentController.java*

```
package javafxapplication1;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import java.io.*;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {


    @FXML
    private TreeView<String> subjectList;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    }

    private void getSubjects(){
        TreeItem<String> subjectRoot = new TreeItem<String> ("Subject");
        subjectRoot.setExpanded(true);
        try {
            BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader("subjects.txt")
            );
            String subject = null;
            String description = null;
            while((subject = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                description = fileReader.readLine();
                TreeItem<String> subjectTree = new TreeItem<String> (subject);
                TreeItem<String> descriptionItem = new TreeItem<String> (description);
                subjectTree.getChildren().add(descriptionItem);
                subjectRoot.getChildren().add(subjectTree);

            }  
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        subjectList.setRoot(subjectRoot);
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        getSubjects();
    }      
}
```

JavaFXApplication1.Java

```
package javafxapplication1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the CSS class is working as you expect.

The problem is: The `TreeView` contains `TreeCell`s. These `TreeCell`s will wrap its text, in case of they will have not enough vertical space to grow vertically. As the `TreeView` has a built in "`ScrollPane`" which ones view-port will grow vertically, it will provide enouth space for the `TreeCell` instances in any case to grow, therefore the wrapping will never be enabled.

To avoid this you could set the [cell factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) to generate the `TreeCell` instances manually. And then you can bind the [`prefWidthProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#prefWidthProperty--) of these elements to the [`widthProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#widthProperty--) of the `TreeView`.

**Example**

```
public class WrappedTreeView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 200, 400);
        Group sceneRoot = (Group) scene.getRoot();

        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toString());

        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Root");
        root.setExpanded(true);

        TreeItem<String> childNode1 = new TreeItem<>("I am a very long node - the first one -, my text must be wrapped! If it is not wrapped, it's a problem!");
        TreeItem<String> childNode2 = new TreeItem<>("I am a very long node - the second one -, my text must be wrapped! If it is not wrapped, it's a problem!");
        TreeItem<String> childNode3 = new TreeItem<>("I am a very long node - the third one -, my text must be wrapped! If it is not wrapped, it's a problem!");

        root.getChildren().addAll(childNode1, childNode2, childNode3);
        childNode2.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>("And I am a very long embedded node, so my text must be wrapped!"));

        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(root);
        treeView.setCellFactory(item -> {
            TreeCell<String> treeCell = new TreeCell<String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item != null && !empty)
                        setText(item);
                    else
                        setText("");
                }
            };

            treeCell.prefWidthProperty().bind(treeView.widthProperty().subtract(5.0));
            return treeCell;
        });

        treeView.setMaxWidth(200);

        sceneRoot.getChildren().add(treeView);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

*The content of application.css*

```
.tree-cell { 
    -fx-wrap-text: true;
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
}
```

*And the generated `TreeView`:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the tree cell's prefWidth value in a treecell cellfactory (along with the treecell's wraptext value to true), which will then stop the cell from expanding horizontally with a scrollPane.